# C - Array in an array

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I want to have a static array with arrays in it. I know you can make a normal array like this:

```
int test[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

But I want to do something like this (Xcode gives me a bunch of warnings and stuff):

```
int test[] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

In python it would be:

```
arr = [[1,2], [3,4]];
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have a multidimensional array, you'd need two levels of arrays:

```
int test[][] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

However, that **will not work**, as you need to declare the size of the inner-most arrays except the last one:

```
int test[2][] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

Or if you need an even stricter type safety:

```
int test[2][2] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

Comment: COOKIES! I LOOOOOOOOOVE COOKIES!

Comment: I think it's the other way around actually, i.e. [][2]. It wouldn't compile for me at least unless I did it that way.

Comment: I use gcc 4.0. Apparently this is the default setting if you use iPhone OS 2.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `typedef` like this

```
typedef int data[2];
data arr[] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

This approach may be clearer if you use a "good" name for the type definition

Answer (score 0):

You need array of arrays or 2 dimensional arrays :

```
int test[][] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

**EDIT** : I am out of touch with C. This is almost correct but not entirely as shown by LiraNuna.